# Responce.redirect error

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

In the login check of my personal webpage i am using

```
Response.Redirect("~/ClientCenter/Default.aspx")
```

and get the *Property evaluation failed* error

I guess i should set the overloaded option endResponce = False

...but for what reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for your problem is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider checking that URL of yours. The tilde might not be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

see Response.redirect call the Response.End which internally call Applicaiton_End Event n this result your current thread get aborted forcefully.... To avoid this v use overloaded Response.redirect with false parameter which says no to Response.End.

I hope u got some clue..